# Генерация случайного символа и замена в char array

Tags: c++, массивы

Допустим у нас есть некий массив:

```
char myChar[] = "Something";
```

Мне нужно сделать для каждого элемента массива генерацию рандомного символа из набора:

```
&@?!#%^*
```

Гуглю плохо, прошу не закидывать тапками, если решение уже есть в паблике.

Comment: Перенёс из вопроса, далее ТС: EDIT: буду благодарен, если ещё научите нормально оформлять тему, BB-коды не работают, кроме них ничего не знаю.

Comment: Посмотрите [справку по оформлению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: По поводу оформления, используется [markdown синтаксис](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) (на большинство тем в руководстве можно кликнуть для получения более подробной справки). Также можно смотреть разметку ответов/вопросов других участников, нажав «править».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не очень понятно, что вы хотите. Заменить буквы случайными символами? Что-то вроде этого?

```
char myChar[] = "Something";
for(char * c = myChar; *c; ++c)
{
    *c = "&@?!#%^*"[rand()%8];
}
```

Comment: Да, поняли вы меня верно